# Is it okay to link to Stack Overflow questions/answers in code comments?

Tags: support

Sometimes I link to related Stack Overflow questions/answers in code comments. Is this fine?

Comment: "Okay" as in, "good programming practice", or as in "allowed / accepted by the community"? The latter, definitely.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: Not if you just link.

Comment: @Pekka The latter.

Comment: @com I don't see why it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Pekka Ok, thanks. :)

Comment: In your own code, or in another answer?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Own code in my own application.

Comment: You can put a link to a [se] question or answer anywhere you'd like: in your code comments, on your web site, on a blog, in a newsletter, an email, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Why wouldn't it be?  First off, the actual *content* is CC-by-SA, meaning you could incorporate it into your code comments if you wanted to with attribution -- so surely a URL, which isn't even the content, would be ok.

Second, nobody's asserting ownership of the URLs.  In fact that would be counter-productive; the whole point of putting things on the web is to get people to look at them, for which you need a URL.